# Nginx on Cent OS Server throws 404 not found

Tags: html, nginx, centos, http-status-code-404

Nginx throw 404 not found Error on html page

my index.html page is in /var/www/html directory

and nginx default configuration is given here:

```
server 
{
    listen   80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/www/html;
    index        index.html index.htm;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

}
```

Comment: The include statement should not be there

Comment: I have removed include statement then also it doen't work.